# C++ Class with Rcpp::Function member

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Using Rcpp, I would like to be able to create a C++ class that has a `Rcpp::Function` for a field. For example:

```
class myClass{
    Rcpp::Function myR_fun;
    myClass(Rcpp::Function userR_fun){
        myR_fun = userR_fun;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work. When compiling, the following error is reported:

```
error: constructor for 'myClass' must explicitly initialize the member 'myR_fun'
which does not have a default constructor
    myClass(Rcpp::Function userR_fun){
    ^
```

The error report is  a bit confusing, because I think I have initialized `myR_fun` in the constructor for `myClass`?

A workaround I could use is to have a void pointer

```
class myClass{
    void* vFunPtr;
    myClass(Rcpp::Function userR_fun){
        vFunPtr = &userR_fun;
    }
};
```

but this seems suboptimal from an organizational perspective. What is the proper way to make an `Rcpp::Function` object to be a field of a C++ class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your syntax, `myR_fun` is first default-constructed, then assigned `userR_fun`.

Try this instead:

```
class myClass {
    Rcpp::Function myR_fun;
    myClass(Rcpp::Function userR_fun)
        : myR_fun(userR_fun)
    {}
};
```

With this syntax `myR_fun` is directly constructed using `userR_fun`.

Comment: That'll do 'er! Thanks!